# PHP Form Inserting to MySQL NULL Values Allowed

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form which submits to a php file which inserts data to a table in MySQL there a some fields in this form which may not be filled in and if this is the case the record doesn't get inserted even though I have set the field in MySQL to accept nulls

My Code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "includes/connection.php";

    $title          = $_POST['inputTitle'];
    $firstname      = $_POST['inputFirstname'];
    $lastname       = $_POST['inputLastName'];
    $address1       = $_POST['inputAddress1'];
    $address2       = $_POST['inputAddress2'];
    $city           = $_POST['inputCity'];
    $county         = $_POST['inputCounty'];
    $postcode       = $_POST['inputPostcode'];
    $email          = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $homephone      = $_POST['inputHomephone'];
    $mobilephone    = $_POST['inputMobilephone'];
    $userid         = $_POST['inputUserID'];

    if($title == '' || $firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $address1 == '' || $address2 == '' || $city == '' || $county == '' || $postcode == '' || $email == '' || $homephone == '' || $mobilephone == '' || $userid == ''){
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'error';
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact
                (`id`,`user_id`,`title`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`county`,`postcode`,`email`,`homephone`,`mobilephone`)
VALUES(NULL,'$userid','$title','$firstname','$lastname','$address1','$address2','$city','$county','$postcode','$email','$homephone','$mobilephone')") or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
    }
    header("location: contacts.php");
?>
```

can anyone tell me what I need to change to sort this issue out?

Best

Justin

P.s sorry if the code block is a bit long but I think it is relevant in this question.

Comment: Add "if (mysql_error()) echo mysql_error()'" before $_SESSION['status'] = 'success'; and comment out header("location: contacts.php"); to see  if there were any sql errors. If there were - post it here.

Comment: The code lenght is fine. Your table structure would be good, too. Have a look at [Bobby Tables: PHP](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) on how to protect against SQL injection. Also, if one of the values is an empty string, the resulting row in MySQL would not have null values, but empty strings!

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Can you be more specific? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your assignement (for the null-able columns), like

```
$title = empty( $_POST['inputTitle'] )
 ? 'NULL'
 : "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['inputTitle'] ) . "'"
;
```

And in your query you have to remove the quotes around the variables.

Comment: Thank you for this could you show in my example above where to do this?

Comment: instead of $title=$_POST['inputTitle']